# Medical Insurance Premium paid by non-earning spouse - Tax Deductible?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, health-insurance, unemployment, premiums

My wife has been a non earning (looking for job) member of the family throughout this year, but has been paying for Medical Insurance Premium for whole family through her savings. She was getting Unemployment Income for first 6 months of this year. She paid close to $14K.

We file joint return. Is that premium tax deductible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you itemize your deductions, and assuming that the sum of all your medical expenses exceeds 10.0% of your Adjusted Gross Income (AGI), then your medical expenses (including the insurance premiums) after that threshold are deductible.

Putting some numbers in to make it less abstract, suppose your AGI is $100,000, and the sum of all your medical expenses is $22,500, then you have a medical deduction of `$22,500 - ($100,000 * 0.10) = $12,500`.

Comment: The floor for medical was 7.5% AGI for 2017 and 2018, but is **10% AGI** for 2019 and later. (Until the next time Congress changes it.) And of course you _benefit_ from itemizing only if your (total) itemized deductions exceed the standard deduction, which is $24,400 for MFJ in 2019.

Comment: @dave_thompson.  Thanks.  I woke up a few minutes ago 03:10 my time and said OMG! and came to the computer to correct.